# Online shops SSL certificates and VISA/MasterCard

Tags: tls, sha

Is it still allowed to use SHA-1 certificates on VISA/MasterCard payment pages?

If yes, will it be prohibited and when?

I know about browsers are going to show it as non-secure after some time, but want to know about VISA/MasterCard guidelines.

Comment: The PCI DSS is where this will appear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it is not (and hasn't been for years).  Use of a SHA-1 certificate will trigger a failure in any current compliance audit.

[U.S. NIST and PCI regulations currently require the use SHA-2.](https://www.entrust.com/lp/sha-1-sha-2-faq/)

[Or for more detail](https://www.entrust.com/sha-2-care/):

> PCI compliance scanners currently require their clients to use SHA-2-compatible SSL certificates. In order to validate PCI DSS compliance, you must ensure that Web server(s) in the PCI environment are configured to disallow SSL (Secure Sockets Layer) Version 2, as well as weak ciphers and hashes. PCI network scanners finding SHA-1 certificates will fail a compliance audit.

Comment: Is it only US related? What about online shop in Japan?

Comment: @Rambalac It's international.  The [Payment Card Industry Data Security Standard (PCI DSS)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Payment_Card_Industry_Data_Security_Standard) `is a proprietary information security standard for organizations that handle branded credit cards from the major card schemes including Visa, MasterCard, American Express, Discover, and JCB.`  If you want to process their credit cards, you'll be held tp PCI DSS for determining liability of fraudulent charges, regardless of which country you're in.